# Whats the name of the font used in this Mickey Mouse birthday banner?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

Can anyone identify the happy birthday font? Whatthefont's closest match is Lithos Pro, but it's not.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

### Pictured: Disney Mickey Stencil Font

The banner in the imaged appears to be created using a Cricut stencil cutting font called [Disney Mickey Font](https://shop.cricut.com/en_us/disney-reg-mickey-font.html) (hence the picture of the craft project). An image of all the glyphs is available from [here](http://cartridgelibrary.com/disney-mickey-font/):

[image]

### Closest Match: Wicked Mouse

The closest downloadable replica I was able to find was [Wicked Mouse by Sharkshock](https://www.dafont.com/wicked-mouse.font?text=HAPPY+BIRTHDAY) (free for personal use, license available for commercial use)

[image: font sample for Wicked Mouse by Sharkshock]

Answer (score 0):

Hello @icecreamtrip you can find the font on the below link

[Mickey Font](http://www.dafont.com/mickey.font)

Though i advise you to read privacy and T&C policies:)

Comment: Somewhat close but not a match there, B is not as clean and other letters either